# Why does free function crash after using qsort in the allocated memory?

Tags: c, crash, malloc, free, qsort

I'm allocating memory for a string using `malloc`, then I execute `qsort` over that memory sorting the characters of the string.

I execute `qsort` several times copying new values to the allocated memory each time.

After that I try to `free` the memory but it crashes

It doesn't crash if I comment the `qsort` line

```
/**
 * Iterates over b finding permutations of s
 *
 * @param s smaller string
 * @param b bigger string
 * @param locations array for the result
 * @return number of locations
 */
int substring_permutations(const char *s, const char *b, int *locations) {
    int s_len = (int) strlen(s);

    char *sorted_sub_b = malloc((s_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    sorted_sub_b[s_len] = '\0';

    char *sorted_s = malloc((s_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    sorted_s[s_len] = '\0';
    sort_string(s, s_len, sorted_s);

    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(b) - s_len + 1; i++) {
        sort_string(b + i, s_len, sorted_sub_b);

        if (strcmp(sorted_s, sorted_sub_b) == 0) {
            locations[l++] = i;
        }
    }

    free(sorted_s);
```

```
    free(sorted_sub_b); // Why does this crash?
```

```
    return l;
}

void sort_string(const char *s, int s_len, char *sorted_s) {
    memcpy(sorted_s, s, s_len * sizeof(char));
    qsort(sorted_s, s_len * sizeof(char), sizeof(char), chrcmp);
}

int chrcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(char *) a - *(char *) b;
}
```

It crashes when executing the second `free`

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

**EDIT**: Adding the calling code

```
int main() {
    const char *s = "abbc";
    const char *b = "cbabadcbbabbcbabaabccbabc";

    printf("%s\n", s);
    printf("%s\n", b);

    size_t s_len = strlen(s);
    size_t b_len = strlen(b);
    int *locations = malloc((b_len + 1 - s_len) * sizeof(char));

    int permutations = substring_permutations(s, b, locations);

    for (int i = 0; i < permutations; i++) {
        int location = locations[i];
        printf("%d ", location);
        print_chars(b + location, s_len);
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(locations);

    return 0;
}

void print_chars(const char *c, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: I see the problem now, it was in the calling code:

I had

```
    int *locations = malloc((b_len + 1 - s_len) * sizeof(char));
```

instead of

```
    int *locations = malloc((b_len + 1 - s_len) * sizeof(int));
```

Thank you @user5329483

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm unable to reproduce the crash. Could you provide the calling code? Also, `sizeof(char)` should be 1, so the fact that `s_len * sizeof(char)` shouldn't matter, but typically this is just `s_len` anyway.

Comment: Without knowing how your function is called (e.g. how is memory the pointers point at is actually allocated) it's only possible to guess.   To get a useful answer, you need to provide a [mcve].  My guess: When passing `b+i` as the first argument to `sort_string()`, presumably a smaller value than `s_len` needs to be passed as the second argument, to avoid a buffer overflow.   Unrelated:  the call of `qsort()` should not be referring to `sizeof(char)` in the second argument - that sort of thing is wrong, even if you're getting lucky since `sizeof(char)` is 1, but won't work for other types.

Comment: The `+1` in the for statement seems to be wrong and should be removed. What is the size of the `location` array?

Comment: Consider using `int *locations = malloc(maxCount * sizeof(*locations));` which allocate always the appropriate number of bytes for your array.